# Customizing Doxygen output for an .ini configuration file

Tags: doxygen, ini

Is there a way to customize the HTML output for an `.ini` configuration file with incorporated comments, as for example:

```
[MySection]
;This is an extensive description of MyParameter (possibly with @commands after semicolon?)
MyParameter=MyValue
```

Despite this is a special usage, I would like to have each parameter parsed/listed separately with description (and unit? and recommended value?). The file could also look like this:

```
[MySection]
;@brief A brief description
;@details A detailled description
;@unit cows (The physical unit of the parameter)
;@recommendedValue 5 cows
MyParameter=7
```

Currently, I'm including the `.ini` file with `@include/@verbinclude` - unfortunately, without syntax highlighting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm assuming that you included the file using the `FILE_PATTERNS` tag, so that at least the file is listed in your documentation. Additionally you have to set `EXTENSION_MAPPING` tag to tell doxygen how to interpret this file. Unfortunately the INI file syntax is not supported by doxygen. At this point you have two possibilities:

1. Writing a custom input-filter (e.g. in perl) and add this as `INPUT_FILTER`
2. Varying the comments so that the doxygen parser gets a valid code corresponding to the programming language you have defined in `EXTENSION_MAPPING`.
   For example if you have set `EXTENSION_MAPPING = ini=C` Then your inifile should look like this:

   ```
   ;/// @file myinifile.ini

   ;/// @brief A brief description.
   ;/// @details A detailled description.
   ;/// @unit cows (The physical unit of the parameter)
   ;/// @recommendedValue 5 cows
   MyParameter=7
   ;
   ```

   The additional slashes `///` are needed to tell the doxygen parser that this line is a comment line which shall be processed by the doxygen.
   Also note the last semicolon `;` which is needed since the doxygen C parser is expecting a closing `;` after each declaration.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any further documentation on INPUT_FILTER on how the standard output should look like? I'd prefer to write the filter in C++?